# Windows Phone Programming Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

I am programming some applications for the Windows Phone and am looking for some standard debugging practices that I cannot figure out how to do in a Windows Phone project in Visual Studio.

1. How can I print statements to the command line just for debugging purposes in a windows phone project?
2. Can I use `MessageBox.show()` (it seems that I cannot import System.Windows.Forms)

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Debbugger.Log which will output to debug window

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.log(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you cannot import System.Windows.Forms from a Windows Phone project. In the case of WP7 you will program using a subset of Silverlight. With that in mind, there is a Message Box control in Silverlight for WP7 using the System.Windows namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox(VS.95).aspx

I suggest that you approach your debugging needs by leveraging unit tests instead of printing to the Message Box.

Comment: Also, never underestimate the power of Unit Tests combined with the "Immediate Window": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For **advanced tracing and logging** you may want to take a look on

[Silverlight and WP7 Exception Handling and Logging building block](http://silverlightlogging.codeplex.com/)

[NLog for Windows Phone](http://nlog-project.org/2011/01/09/nlog-for-windows-phone-7.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can simply use `Debug.WriteLine(Something);` just like `Console.WriteLine(Something);`. The `Something` will automatically be converted to string. This is as simple as it can get.
2. As indicated, you can indeed use `MessageBox` control. It's present in `System.Windows` namespace. You can also use some third party toolkit like Coding4Fun if you need customized messagebox.

Comment: I cannot do Using System.Windows either.